# how to get data by restfull api in codeigniter

Tags: rest, codeigniter, printf

I would like to showing data by `print_r();` but the error say "Trying Property to get Object", im using RestFull api. siup is one of field in my table.

this is my script :

```
$data = $this->restf->request('car/find','get',array('id'=>$id));
print_r($data->siup);
```

Comment: can you pls print $data??

Comment: error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: use print_r($data); and let me know what is output?

Comment: example roytuts.com/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-get-example/